# MySQL commands work locally but fail when uploaded to TuxFamily

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm making a website that enables easy sharing of Public PGP keys. The site uses PHP and MySQL on the back end and JavaScript on the front end. The site works fine on localhost, but I have just uploaded it to TuxFamily, and it doesn't work.

I am unable to find out what the problem is with my query because I have no access to any error information generated by MySQL or PHP. I'm only left to guess what the problem is and I have a feeling it's the query...

Anyway here's the code :

index.php : http://pastebin.com/TqJryvC2

inc/pgpshare.class.php : http://pastebin.com/XXMv2PjK

The PHP is able to create a MySQL connection correctly and all the functions in `pgpshare.class.php` seem to work as expected except `if($user1key = $pgpshare->GetUser1Key($id))` (index.php:14).

Please help me to figure out why this is failing.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: What makes you think you don't have access to `$mysqli->error`? Also have you tried using `error_reporting(E_ALL), ini_set('display_errors', '1')` to view PHP errors?

Comment: Why don't you atleast echo the error messages in index file which you wrote? It'l tell you that may be id is invalid.... 1st see where it returns false.
And why can't you access mysqli errors?

Comment: I have tried to access $mysqli->error, in this case $pgpshare->mysqli->error, but have never had any output whatsoever :(

Comment: Even if you enable error reporting in the php file, the host somehow still blocks it for unknown reasons

Answer (score 0):

You should print errors out for instance with $mysqli->error, if this doesn't work you can always add something like that:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($1, $2, $3, $4)or die('Connection error: '.$mysqli->error);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)or die('Prepare failed: '.$mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_params($1, $2)or die('Bind_param failed: '.$stmt->error);
```

Even if mysqli->error is empty, you'll always know which function failed.
And make sure your using $stmt->error ($query->error in your case) in the functions atfer the prepare function.

> $query->bind_param("ssss", $id, $key, $user2key, $ip);

I think $id is an interger so use "i":

```
$query->bind_param("isss", $id, $key, $user2key, $ip);
```

- http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Also don't forget to change your connection data (host, user, pw, db) by changing to another Server.

*- Minding*